Polynomial invariants under group actions on algebras
I have a question regarding the space of polynomials invariant under group actions on algebras satisfying certain properties.
Question
Let $k$ be a field (let's say $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$) and $V$ an algebra over $k$ of finite dimension, with the commutative product denoted by $*$.
Let $G$ be a group that acts on $V$ linearly and whose action is distributive wrt the product of $V$: $\forall x,y \in V, g \in G, g \cdot (x * y) = (g \cdot x) * (g \cdot y)$.
Let $W \subset V$ be the space of points that are fixed under $G$, i.e. $W = \{x \in V\ |\ \forall g \in G, g \cdot x = x\}$.
We define $\mathbf{\Phi}$ as the algebra of morphisms of $V$ generated by $G$-equivariant endomorphisms (i.e. linear maps) of $V$.
That is we consider all the functions $f \in End(V)$ such that
$$
\forall g \in G, \forall x \in V,\ g \cdot f(x) = f(g\cdot x),
$$
and construct $\mathbf{\Phi}$ by considering finite products and sums of these functions.
Given the definition of $\mathbf{\Phi}$ and the fact that $G$'s action is distributive on both operations of $V$, it is clear that every $\phi \in \mathbf{\Phi}$ is itself $G$-equivariant.
In addition, if $\theta \in {V^*}^G$, where ${V^*}^G$ is the space of $G$-invariant linear forms on $V$, then $\theta \circ \phi$ is $G$-invariant and can be considered as a polynomial on $V$ by choosing a basis of $V$.
Therefore, we can say that $\theta \circ \phi \in {k[V]}^G$.
Are there non-trivial conditions on $G$ (and possibly on $k$) under which the converse is true?
That is, are there conditions under which for every $P \in {k[V]}^G$, we can find $\phi \in \mathbf{\Phi}$ and $\theta \in {V^*}^G$ such that $P = \theta \circ \phi$ (up to a constant in $W$)?
Given the assumptions, we can restrict ourselves to a finite basis of homogeneous polynomials of ${k[V]}^G$ and see if they can be expressed as in the hypothesis.
Motivation
The formulated question is kept fairly general, but it came to me as I was thinking of this specific problem for $V$ being the space of real symmetric matrices with $X*Y = \frac{1}{2} \left( XY + YX\right)$ and $G$ a subgroup of the matrix orthogonal group (possibly finite).
So if the hypothesis is not true for some examples under these conditions, I'd be interested in seeing specific counterexamples.
This product however is not associative, so it may result in more difficulties.
Possible further assumptions
If that makes things easier, here are some suggestions of further assumptions for which I would be interested in a result as well:

We could assume that the action of $G$ is unitary, such that $V$ can be decomposed into an orthogonal direct sum of irreducible subspaces.
Under this unitary action assumption, we could also assume that the inner product on $V$ is given by the composition of a linear form on $V$ and of the product on that space. This is the case for the example given in the motivation section.
Although I'm particularly interested in $k = \mathbb{R}$, assuming that $k = \mathbb{C}$ could help by making the elements of $\mathbf{\Phi}$ easily representable as a weighted sum of products of orthogonal projections on the irreducible subspaces of $V$. So that may help in formulating a result.

